# Unable to start the chipKit BasicIOShield with PIC32 using PICKIT3 programmer

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, led, mplab, pic32

I have chipKit uC32 (PIC32MX340F512H) ,chipkit BasicIOShield  and PICkit3
programmer all from the Microchip.

I'm using MPLABX IDE.

Since I'm very new to this so I didn't know where to start I have searched and look at the web and find only tutorial which using MPIDE  which I'm not allowed to use in my project.
I have read the Reference manual and Data sheet for and make test project but any way the uC32 Board refuse to recognize the BasicIOShield and I was unable to connect this two together.

Any tips and link would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Basic IO shield Reference manual stated that you should follow some step in order to make the ChipKit to talk to the basic IO shield.

**Power on sequence**

> > 1. Apply power to VDD.
> > 2. Send Display Off command.
> > 3. Initialize display to desired operating mode.
> > 4. Clear screen.
> > 5. Apply power to VBAT.
> > 6. Delay 100ms.
> > 7. Send Display On command.

**Power off sequence**

> > 1. Send Display Off command.
> > 2. Power off VBAT.
> > 3. Delay 100ms.
> > 4. Power off VDD.

The shield is using SPI2. The following registers are used 
RF4, RF5, RF6 and RG9 
Also you must change the jumper in the uC32 from LED4 to JP4 and JP8.
in the Appendix B of the reference manual of the basic IO shield is an example code which is useful.